# Zurb Foundation SCSS: Can't find bower

Tags: ruby, zurb-foundation, bower

I'm trying to create a new foundation project with Ruby through the Windows command prompt. Every time I try to create a new project I get this error message:

```
Can't find bower. You can install it by running: sudo npm install -g bower
```

What is the Windows command for this? I've tried `gem install bower` but still get the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Bower on Windows, you must install Git correctly. Install Git first and then use git prompt to install bower. Download and install [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realize you had to do this through the GIT prompt.

Comment: how did you install bower from the git prompt? i have the same problem and i can't figure how...