# Foundation cant find bower

Tags: node.js, zurb-foundation, bower

I'm trying to create my first foundation 5 project with sass, but keep getting this message:

> Can't find bower. You can install it by running: sudo npm install -g bower

I already run bower install and it seems to go ok.  The components report 304 but i get 1.2.8 for bower -v. Then i try again to create the foundation project and get the same result.

I'm on windows 7 by the way...

Comment: Seems that [this answer][1] can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979042/zurb-foundation-scss-cant-find-bower

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a PATH issue.

I'm up and running now!

For the records:

```
    C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

should exist in

```
   PATH
```

for both **"User Variables"** and **"System Variables"**